# -bash: ngrok: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku, ngrok

I'm trying to integrate the Twilio API into my Rails app. The tutorial I found suggested using ngrok to put my app on the internet (rather than working on localhost). I've installed and upnzipped ngrok, and when I try to call it from the directory it is in, I get:

```
-bash: ngrok: command not found.
```

Does anyone know what my problem might be? Also could anyone explain what ngrok does vs deploying to heroku? If heroku would work the same, I would just do that. I'm new to using APIs, though, so I'm not clear on why I'm using ngrok.

Thanks!

Comment: I _want_ to say this is off-topic... I believe this goes in SuperUser or Unix&Linux. (Although I see why you put this in Stack Exchange, it would fit best on other sites due to it being about operating Linux and not about programming.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the binary is not located in one of the folders stored in the environment variable $PATH you have to provide at least a relative path to your current location. So if you are in the same folder as the binary then you have to call it with `./ngrok`

Comment: Also make sure the file exists with `ls` ;)

Answer (score 18):

To access from any directory I had to move the binary to $PATH

```
mv ngrok /usr/local/bin
```

in order to call executable from everywhere.

UPDATE: `brew install ngrok` no longer works because:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "ngrok"
Upstream sunsetted 1.x in March 2016 and 2.x is not open-source.
```

So you'll need to download binary from https://ngrok.com/download

As for question "What does ngrok do vs Heroku?", ngrok is totally different than Heroku, which is more complex.  Ngrok allows you to expose a running local server over the internet using a secure tunnel.  Heroku is a cloud hosting platform for web applications.  To use ngrok you can just run your local server and expose it via ngrok.  Anyone who connects via ngrok to your server is actually communicating to a server running you YOUR local machine.  With Heroku, your application is running on hosted virtual machines in the cloud.  That is an oversimplification, but in short, NGROk is good for very fast testing of your server by some remote users.  It can also be useful for transferring files / data etc. from inside a virtualized environment i.e. a cloud ssh session.

Comment: Better answer .

Answer (score 0):

Below Trick  did the work for me

I have downloaded the ngrok from below site :
https://ngrok.com/download

unzip the folder and  put the ngrok file  with extention (Unix Executable File)inside
**/usr/local/bin** folder.

Answer (score -1):

the command has changed to: ngrok http 80

Examples from ngrok:

> ```
> ngrok http 80                    # secure public URL for port 80 web server
> ngrok http -subdomain=baz 8080   # port 8080 available at baz.ngrok.io
> ngrok http foo.dev:80            # tunnel to host:port instead of localhost
> ngrok tcp 22                     # tunnel arbitrary TCP traffic to port 22
> ngrok tls -hostname=foo.com 443  # TLS traffic for foo.com to port 443
> ngrok start foo bar baz          # start tunnels from the configuration file
> ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  User wanted to know way base command `ngrok` returns `command not found`.